# Can not read proper buildozer logcat

Tags: python, kivy, logcat, buildozer

Could you please help me to find location of error in my main.py code. Below is extract of logcat:

```
I/python  ( 6494):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  ( 6494):    File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
I/python  ( 6494):      Builder.load_file('verbs.kv')
I/python  ( 6494):    File "/data/data/com.seafarershobby.verbosirregulares/files/app/crystax_python/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 290, in load_file
I/python  ( 6494):      data = fd.read()
I/python  ( 6494):    File "/data/data/com.seafarershobby.verbosirregulares/files/app/crystax_python/stdlib.zip/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
I/python  ( 6494):  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14254: ordinal not in range(128)
I/python  ( 6494): Python for android ended.
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is in inside your question.

```
> File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
```

Comment: Line 17 is: Builder.load_file('verbs.kv'). But what wrong with that?